# Visibility in an OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, visibility

I have these TextViews on ImageViews. When you click an ImageView, the text on that particular ImageView should appear and the rest of the TextViews on the other ImageViews should disappear. How can I do this?

I know it's to do with if/else statements, but cannot seem to figure out what exactly I should use with these statements.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    //Declaring instance variable of FirebaseAuth as stated on Firebase Authentication file.
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //Declaring the Toolbar instance variable.
    private Toolbar mMainAppBar;
    //ViewPager on the activity_main.xml file
    private ViewPager mMainActivityViewPager;
    private TextView mShopTextView;
    private TextView mSocialTextView;
    private TextView mChatTextView;
    private TextView mInventoryTextView;
    private TextView mSettingsTextView;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing mAuth and the .getInstance() method indicates that there is only a single instance variable for FirebaseAuth.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        //Setting the App Bar on the MainActivity page.
        mMainAppBar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar);
        //setSupportActionBar a command given in AppCombatActivity to make the Actionbar a Toolbar.
        //Toolbar is a new view that was introduced to Android to make the designing of Actionbar more flexible.
        setSupportActionBar(mMainAppBar);

        mShopTextView = findViewById(R.id.shopTextView);
        mSocialTextView = findViewById(R.id.socialTextView);
        mChatTextView = findViewById(R.id.chatTextView);
        mInventoryTextView = findViewById(R.id.inventoryTextView);
        mSettingsTextView = findViewById(R.id.settingsTextView);

        mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);



          //Setting up the clicking of ImageViews on the Bottom Navigation bar.
        //How I did it: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/starting-a-fragment-from-an-activity
        ImageView shopImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shopImageView);

        shopImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShopFragment shopFragment = new ShopFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, shopFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        });

        ImageView socialImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.socialImageView);

        socialImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SocialFragment socialFragment = new SocialFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, socialFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                TextView socialTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.socialTextView);
                socialTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ImageView chatImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chatImageView);

        chatImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ChatFragment chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, chatFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                TextView chatTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.chatTextView);
                chatTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ImageView inventoryImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inventoryImageView);

        inventoryImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                InventoryFragment inventoryFragment = new InventoryFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, inventoryFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                TextView inventoryTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inventoryTextView);
                inventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ImageView settingsImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settingsImageView);

        settingsImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, settingsFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                TextView settingsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inventoryTextView);
                settingsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


    }
```

EDIT: 
Here is what the bar looks like: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InJtx.png).

all those icons are ImageViews and the "hello" are TextViews. When I click one ImageView, I want that particular TextView to appear and all the other TextViews to disappear.

Comment: Can you post the image for clear understanding

Comment: @Sniffer I added it to the original post.

Comment: You can do it with data binding with LiveData or Observable property, something like that:                                                                           
 <TextView              
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="@{item.isSelected == ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>

Comment: If that view is placed at the bottom? then you should go with the [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView) it has an inbuilt provision to achieve such behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer by `Momen Zaqout` is correct
I'll just rewrite the code in a more optimized way

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

```
//Declaring instance variable of FirebaseAuth as stated on Firebase Authentication file.
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
//Declaring the Toolbar instance variable.
private Toolbar mMainAppBar;
//ViewPager on the activity_main.xml file
private ViewPager mMainActivityViewPager;
private  TextView mShopTextView,mSocialTextView,mChatTextView,mInventoryTextView,mSettingsTextView;
private ImageView shopImageView,socialImageView,chatImageView,inventoryImageView,settingsImageView;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing mAuth and the .getInstance() method indicates that there is only a single instance variable for FirebaseAuth.
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    //Setting the App Bar on the MainActivity page.
    mMainAppBar = findViewById(R.id.mainToolBar);
    //setSupportActionBar a command given in AppCombatActivity to make the Actionbar a Toolbar.
    //Toolbar is a new view that was introduced to Android to make the designing of Actionbar more flexible.
    setSupportActionBar(mMainAppBar);

    mShopTextView = findViewById(R.id.shopTextView);
    mSocialTextView = findViewById(R.id.socialTextView);
    mChatTextView = findViewById(R.id.chatTextView);
    mInventoryTextView = findViewById(R.id.inventoryTextView);
    mSettingsTextView = findViewById(R.id.settingsTextView);

    shopImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shopImageView);
    socialImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.socialImageView);
    chatImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chatImageView);
    inventoryImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inventoryImageView);
    settingsImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.settingsImageView);

    shopImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    socialImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    chatImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    inventoryImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
    settingsImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

    mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.shopImageView:
                ShopFragment shopFragment = new ShopFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, shopFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break();

            case R.id.socialImageView:
                SocialFragment socialFragment = new SocialFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, socialFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                break();


            case R.id.chatImageView:
                ChatFragment chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, chatFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break();


            case R.id.inventoryImageView:
                InventoryFragment inventoryFragment = new InventoryFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, inventoryFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break();


            case R.id.settingsImageView:    
                SettingsFragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, settingsFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      
                mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break();

        }




}
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there a short way of doing it though?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to disappear all textviews and then appear the desired textview.

```
void changeTexViews(View desired ){

       mShopTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSocialTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mChatTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mInventoryTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSettingsTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        desired .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

and in each `ImageView.setOnClickListener`  use this method,

for example

```
shopImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShopFragment shopFragment = new ShopFragment();
                FragmentTransaction transaction =
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.mainActivityFrameLayout, shopFragment);
                transaction.commit();

                changeTexViews(mShopTextView);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**Here I want to provide some help tips to **

if you want hide or show any element first thing is if you want show all element visible at first time you can set by default visibility to  View.VISIBLE else you can use View.Gone.
and after that in which textview or image view click you want show or hide any element you can perform inside the onClickListener() like below example.



ImageView inventoryImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inventoryImageView);
        inventoryImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                demotext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                demoImage.setVisibility(View.Gone)
            }
        });
```